# AS3 FTP file download. Getting extra bytes

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, ftp, byte

I've been trying to download a zip file from our FTP server for our Android app for a little while now, and I'm at a point where I'm not really sure what's going on.

I found [this class](http://pastie.org/8274510) that does a pretty good job, I'm not sure who wrote it, but I found it [here](http://flashandrc.wordpress.com/2013/01/16/downloading-a-file-from-a-ftp-server-with-as3/). Only problem is, I get a few extra bytes from my download and it renders the zip file invalid.

File is **212 180 753** bytes, I receive **213 005 047** bytes.

I have no idea why.

I'm thinking the header must get some weird info, but I'm really out of my league when it comes to both network stuff AND understanding more than basic stuff about how files are "built".

If there's no easy answer, I'd appreciate any link that could help me understand both these subjects better!

**EDIT**: Pier made me realize my solution to download the zip file was not the most effective for this project. I am still curious as to why I get those extra bytes though, so I'll keep on looking into it once my project is done, so any help would still be appreciated!

Comment: why don't you simply download from a URL instead of using FTP?

Comment: Oh my God you're right. I got so caught up in my "solution" I failed to see any other. I have no idea why I went the complicated route first. Don't I feel silly now =/